Next Js 13.4.4 app route facing issue Type error: Type '({ params }: Props) => Promise<Element | null>' is not assignable to type 'FC<Props>'
"next": "^13.4.3", app route
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
I got this error message while compiling pages:
Type error: Type '({ params }: Props) => Promise<Element | null>' is not assignable to type 'FC<Props>'. Type 'Promise<Element | null>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

/blog/[id]/page.tsx
import React, { FC } from 'react'

type Props = {
  params: { id: string }
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }
}

async function getData(id: string) {
  const res = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:9090/v1/blog/${id}`,
    {
      next: { revalidate: 3600 },
    }
  )

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
  return res.json()
}

const page: FC<Props> = async ({ params, searchParams }) => {
  const { id } = params
  const { data: Offering } = await getData(id)

I was expecting to do server-side rending by fetching data on server then sending content to client
